# 'java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed' Error while starting Scala-IDE(Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I am new to eclipse. Please excuse me if I am wrong about something.

I've downloaded Scala IDE for eclipse 4.6.1. I've extracted the contents and tried to launch eclipse. Initially there was a problem with maven: '***Failed to read artifact descriptor for maven-resources-plugin***'. I was able to solve this error(I assume so because it didn't show up again) by adding the proxy settings to settings.xml in .m2 folder.

Now I get a new error saying: '***java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed***'

Below is the full error:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 4 2 2017-07-10 14:34:58.379
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt".
!STACK 0
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:204)
    at scala.tools.scalap.Classfile.<init>(Classfile.scala:17)
    at org.scalaide.core.internal.jdt.model.ScalaClassFileDescriber$.isScala(ScalaClassFileDescriber.scala:16)
    at org.scalaide.core.internal.jdt.model.ScalaClassFileDescriber.describe(ScalaClassFileDescriber.scala:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.describe(ContentTypeCatalog.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.collectMatchingByContents(ContentTypeCatalog.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.internalFindContentTypesFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.internalFindContentTypesFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.findContentTypesFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeMatcher.findContentTypeFor(ContentTypeMatcher.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.modelhandler.ModelHandlerRegistry.getHandlerFor(ModelHandlerRegistry.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl.calculateType(ModelManagerImpl.java:750)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl.getModelForEdit(ModelManagerImpl.java:1427)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.StorageModelProvider.loadModel(StorageModelProvider.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.StorageModelProvider.loadModel(StorageModelProvider.java:705)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.StorageModelProvider.selfCreateModel(StorageModelProvider.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.StorageModelProvider.createModelInfo(StorageModelProvider.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.StorageModelProvider.createElementInfo(StorageModelProvider.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDocumentProvider.connect(AbstractDocumentProvider.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4178)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1466)
    at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor.doSetInput(TextEditor.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.doSetInput(StructuredTextEditor.java:1958)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$5.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2126)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3172)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3197)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.init(StructuredTextEditor.java:2651)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.addPage(FormEditor.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.addPage(FormEditor.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor.addSourcePage(MavenPomEditor.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor.addPages(MavenPomEditor.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages(FormEditor.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:340)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:931)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:975)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1324)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:975)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

I tried to re download eclipse and launch again. But I still get the same error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like incompatible versions. I've had better luck using IntelliJ for Scala.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but still, you may find it helpful. Scala support in eclipse sucks big time. I was an eclipse user myself before I started with scala. After spending a couple of weeks trying to get it to work, I switched to Intellij, and never looked back. It is a superior product all around, but scala support is simply incomparable.

Comment: I agree. I've had issues with network settings on sbt. Never tried Maven on intellij though. @Dima

Comment: Intelij doesn't have the community to support it like eclipse does. I'd recommend using the 'scala IDE for Eclipse' (http://scala-ide.org) version that is supported by typesafe/ lightbend / Odersky

Comment: I get this issue when I accidentally open eclipse directly (I regularly use a script to open eclipse via command). Marek Jagielski's fix works for my situation

Answer (score 27):

I have similar issue. I manage to open eclipse without creating a new workspace by editing:

workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi

and removing from it all "persistedState" xml nodes.

**UPDATE:**

As other responses and comments says. Deleting file workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi 
seems to work well without side effects.

Comment: In my case it worked. Deleting the file may do as well.

Comment: removing persistedState worked :-) perhaps you're better off deleting it

Comment: i think this get triggered at least for me when i built a spark project and i choose old version of the compiler and my pom was some old plugins

Comment: Way too many persistedState nodes to delete manually.  Go with deleting the file.

Comment: For me this happened straight after installing an m2e lifecycle adapter and (as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/45050696/2526040) leaving pom.xml editors open. Deleting just the persistedState elements for pom.xml editors sorted it for me.

Comment: @javawebapps
 Use  regular expression to delete:   sed -i    's#<persistedState.*/>$##g' workbench.xmi 
Or if you use  notepad++ use "replace all"  with regular expression turned on.

Answer (score 14):

Deleting

```
workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
```

in its entirety also works. A new workbench.xmi is generated after exiting the workspace.

Answer (score 3):

First go to below directory of your PC/Laptop/Desktop etc

**C:\Users\Username\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench**

**workbench.xmi** file  - Delete this file without any worry

Now, start your eclipse and running great as usual.

Answer (score 2):

My repo case for exactly this crash was: Open any POM with m2e editor. The m2e editor tried to open in structured view (not XML mode) despite i have choosen to prefer XMl in preferences. The structured view crashed and created an endless loop of eclipse NPEs in the eclipse event loop. One has to close the window and re-open again. Then the XML views opens. 
As long as you have a POM open (now in XML mode) any restart of this workspace triggers this crash. The workaround (for me) was to close all POM editors before restarting eclipse.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16685905)

Comment: The question was: Any help would be appreciated. I gave a workaround that worked for this scenario. Additionally i do not agree that i asked for any further input.

Comment: @AndreasStiller That message is automatically generated (note "From Review").

Answer (score 0):

I got this error very suddenly after I came back from a three week holiday and opened a workspace that worked perfectly before the holiday.

I have no real solution, but a workaround, that I used:

I renamed the old workspace on the filesystem. Then I created a new workspace with the old name, moved all project folders into the new workspace and imported them again into Eclipse. Could find no other way to solve this.

If someone finds out the root cause and an inplace solutions, I would be very interested.

Answer (score 0):

please report details in ticket on [scala ide issue tracker](https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1002903-scala-assert-prevents-eclipse-start-up/details)

meanwhile add to the eclipse startup script a backup of workspace

```
cp -a workbench.xmi workbench.$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S").xmi
```